# Does a C# preprocessing tool exist?

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

Does anyone know of a utility to preprocess a C# source file without compiling it, in a similar fashion to using the -E flag in GCC? I tried using GCC - it successfully processes `#if` directives, but it chokes on any `#region` directives...

Ideally, I'd like to be able to run the tool over a .cs file to remove any `#if` blocks that evaluate to false, and optionally be able to flag whether to remove/leave intact comments, `#region`, `#pragma` directives etc.

To put this in context, I want to be able to a publish some source code that is part of a (much) larger project, whilst removing portions that are only relevant to the larger project. As an example, there are chunks of code that look like this:

```
#if (SUBPROJECT)
namespace SubProject
#else
namespace CompleteProject
#endif
{
  public class SomeClass()
  {
#if (!SUBPROJECT)
    // This might call a method contained in an assembly that potentially 
    // won't be available to the sub-project, or maybe a method that hooks
    // into a C library via P/Invoke...
    string result = CallSomeCleverMethod();
#else
    // This might call a method that performs a simplified version of the 
    // above, but does so without the above's assembly or P/Invoke 
    // dependencies...
    string result = CallSomeSimpleMethod();
#endif
  }
}
```

Please remember I'm not trying to do builds here - this is purely about publishing only a subset of a larger project's source code.

Any ideas/help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out using the GNU C preprocessor (cpp) directly (rather than via gcc) provides more control over the output. Using this, I was able to process the source files in a suitable fashion...

Here's an example:

```
cpp -C -P -DSUBPROJECT Input.cs Output.cs
```

I tried to get the C/C++ compiler provided with Visual Studio to do something similar, but gave up after a while...

Comment: Where can I obtain the executable?

Comment: It's part of the GNU compiler collection - it's probably already installed if you're running OS X or Linux. If you're running Windows,  MinGW is probably what you need.

Comment: I found one that works here: http://mcpp.sourceforge.net/download.html, but the executable is mccp rather than cpp.

Comment: Unfortunately this has empty lines in the output file. Any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe that there are any flags for the csc or msc (mono compiler) to output the preprocessed files.

If I had to do this, and it was a small subset I would compile and then use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to decompile back to C# and export the files.  If you have a lot of files, there is an [Reflector Add-In](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins) called [FileGenerator for Reflector](http://www.codeplex.com/FileGenReflector).

Unfortunately this will not be a true copy of your codebase -- it will reformat all of the code and you will lose all of the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a preprocessor for C# that would allow you to export a subset of your source code without building it.

However, You should be able to achieve the same effect by using a code generation template. Just change to the preprocesor directives to the appropriate template equivalent.

Visual Studio 2008 has a built-in code generation tool called **[T4](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-creating-reusable-code-generation-templates/)**. There are other third-party options like CodesmithTools or the free **[MyGeneration.Net](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/ScreenShots/ScreenShot1/tabid/69/Default.aspx)**

Comment: That sounds promising - I hadn't thought about T4 - I'll look into it & report back soon..

Answer (score 1):

Might it not be easier, and more idiomatically C#, to create interfaces, and have different implementations of those interfaces? One set that you can package up a as a library and redistribute?

Comment: I need to be able to process actual class/namespace names, metadata (custom attributes etc) - see the namespace example in the question. I also don't want to add implementation complexity where it isn't otherwise needed.

Comment: You don't think the above code is already complex?  I still think you're really coming at this from a C++ mindset and maybe missing some tools that C# offers, but best of luck finding a solution that will make you happy!

Answer (score 1):

I faced this some time ago - had to clean up certain outdated C# preprocessor branches in my old project leaving relevant branches intact. The built-it C preprocessor could not do it for me as its output file never contains preprocessor directives. Of course, there are C processor tools such as **unifdef** or **coan** that can partially remove outdated branches for C/С++. The thing is that they do not fully support С# syntax - they fail on #region and #pragma, for instance. So, I had to write [my own python tool **undefine**](https://github.com/gaDZella/undefine) for my task. I used regexp for parsing directives and the sympy library - for simplifying and calculating logical expressions. To resolve your task try the following:

```
>>python undefine apply -d SUBPROJECT your_project_path
```

The tool worked fine with my large ~10m lines codebase.