# How to avoid implementing INotifyPropertyChanged manually

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, collections

Is there some way to avoid this. I have a lot of classes that are bound to DataGridViews and they are just simple collection of properties with default getter and setter. So these classes are very simple. Now I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface for them which will increase the amount of code a lot.
Is there any class that I can inherit from to avoid writing all this boring code? I image that I can inherit my classes from some class and decorate the properties with some attributes and it will do the magic. Is that possible?

I'm well aware of Aspect Oriented Programming, but I'd rather do it object oriented way.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/notifypropertyweaver/ maybe of use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a container base class, eg:

```
abstract class Container : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  Dictionary<string, object> values;

  protected object this[string name]
  {
    get {return values[name]; }
    set 
    { 
      values[name] = value;
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
  }
}

class Foo : Container
{
  public int Bar 
  {
    {get {return (int) this["Bar"]; }}
    {set { this["Bar"] = value; } }
  }
}
```

Note: very simplified code

Answer (score 9):

It depends; you could use [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp) to write such an attribute that is *re-written* by the weaver; however, I would be tempted to just do it manually - perhaps using a common method for handling the data updates, i.e.

```
private string name;
public string Name {
    get { return name; }
    set { Notify.SetField(ref name, value, PropertyChanged, this, "Name"); }
}
```

with:

```
public static class Notify {
    public static bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value,
         PropertyChangedEventHandler handler, object sender, string propertyName)
    {
        if(!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field,value)) {
            field = value;
            if(handler!=null) {
                handler(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without AOP, I don't think there is an easy way to retrofit this to your existing classes. However you do it, you're at the very least going to have to change all your properties.

I use a base class inheriting INotifyPropertyChanged with an OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) method to fire the event.  I then use a Visual Studio Code snippet to create properties that automatically call OnPropertyChanged in the property setter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar solution to Marc, that has been extended to allow multiple property onpropertychanges and multiple RaiseCanExecuteChanged

simplest example usage

```
string _firstName;
public string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _firstName, value, "FirstName"); }
}
```

advanced example using multiple property updates and multiple commands

```
string _firstName;
public string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _firstName, value, "FirstName", "FullName", Command1, Command2); }
}
```

The advanced example calls OnProperty changed on firstname and fullname and also calls RaiseCanExecuteChanged for command1 and command2

base ViewModel code

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged<T>(ref T field, T value, params object[] updateThese)
{
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
    {
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(updateThese);
    }
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(params object[] updateThese)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        foreach (string property in updateThese.Where(property => property is string))
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));

        foreach (DelegateCommand<object> command in updateThese.Where(property => property is DelegateCommand<object>))
            command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're amenable to AOP, you could try using [PostSharp](http://postsharp.org). Search for PostSharp INotifyPropertyChanged and you'll find lots of articles explaining it, such as [this](http://ruskin-dantra.blogspot.com/2009/03/inotifypropertychanged-made-easier.html) and [this](http://khason.net/dev/inotifypropertychanged-auto-wiring-or-how-to-get-rid-of-redundant-code/).

Answer (score 0):

Using code gen (say, [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)) is another way. Check the discussion at: [Automatic INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation through T4 code generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968406/automatic-inotifypropertychanged-implementation-through-t4-code-generation).

I use this method, and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found [ActiveSharp - Automatic INotifyPropertyChanged](http://activesharp.codeplex.com/), I have yet to use it, but it looks good.

To quote from it's web site...

---

> Send property change notifications
>   without specifying property name as a
>   string.

Instead, write properties like this:

```
public int Foo
{
    get { return _foo; }
    set { SetValue(ref _foo, value); }  // <-- no property name here
}
```

Note that there is no need to include the name of the property as a string. ActiveSharp reliably and correctly figures that out for itself. It works based on the fact that your property implementation passes the backing field (_foo) by ref. (ActiveSharp uses that "by ref" call to identify which backing field was passed, and from the field it identifies the property).

Answer (score 0):

improvements on leepie.

- this handles a case where there is no such element in the `values` dictionary (which results in a `KeyNotFoundException)`
- `avoid passing the name` of the property  ( using `CallerMemberName` attribute )
- use generic methods rather than indexers `(["name"])`.

usage:

```
public class MyViewModel : PropertyChangedHelper
{
    public int Bar
    {
        get => GetProperty<int>();
        set => SetProperty<int>(value);
    }
}
```

code:

```
public class PropertyChangedHelper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public T GetProperty<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        EnsureElement<T>(propertyName);
        return (T) _values[propertyName];
    }

    public void SetProperty<T>(object value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        EnsureElement<T>(propertyName);
        if (_values[propertyName] == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _values[propertyName] = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void EnsureElement<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        if (!_values.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            _values.Add(propertyName, default(T));
        }
    }
}
```

from  : [devto](https://dev.to/themulti0/i-changed-inotifypropertychanged-53m6) 
there is also benchmark in there.