# Simple small INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged

Say I have the following class:

```
public MainFormViewModel
{
    public String StatusText {get; set;}
}
```

What is the easiest smallest way to get my changes to StatusText to reflect to any controls that bind to it?

Obviously I need to use INotifyPropertyChanged, but is there a cool way to do it that does not clutter up my code? need lots of files? etc?

Note: If this is a dupe then I am sorry.  I searched and could not find any thing but using [T4 code Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968406/automatic-inotifypropertychanged-implementation-through-t4-code-generation) which does not sound easy (to setup at least).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately C# doesn't offer an easy mechanism to do that automatically... It has been [suggested](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/40583-wpf-feature-suggestions/suggestions/478802-modify-the-language-to-allow-for-observable-proper?ref=title) to create a new syntax like this :

```
public observable int Foo { get; set; }
```

But I doubt it will ever be included in the language...

A possible solution would to use an AOP framework like [Postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp), that way you just need to decorate your properties with an attribute:

```
public MainFormViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [NotifyPropertyChanged]
    public String StatusText {get; set;}
}
```

(haven't tried, but I'm pretty sure Postsharp allows you to do that kind of thing...)

---

UPDATE: OK, I managed to make it work. Note that it's a very crude implementation, using reflection on a private field to retrieve the delegate... It could certainly be improved, but I'll leave it to you ;)

```
[Serializable]
public class NotifyPropertyChangedAttribute : LocationInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnSetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        object oldValue = args.GetCurrentValue();
        object newValue = args.Value;
        base.OnSetValue(args);
        if (args.Instance is INotifyPropertyChanged)
        {
            if (!Equals(oldValue, newValue))
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(args.Instance, args.LocationName);
            }
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(object instance, string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = GetPropertyChangedHandler(instance);
        if (handler != null)
            handler(instance, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private PropertyChangedEventHandler GetPropertyChangedHandler(object instance)
    {
        Type type = instance.GetType().GetEvent("PropertyChanged").DeclaringType;
        FieldInfo propertyChanged = type.GetField("PropertyChanged",
                                                  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (propertyChanged != null)
            return propertyChanged.GetValue(instance) as PropertyChangedEventHandler;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that your class still need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. You just don't have to explicitly raise the event in your property setters.

Comment: Are you sure that is the link to Postsharp.  Doesn't seem like they offer any tools for C#.

Comment: Oops, sorry, bad link... I fixed it

Comment: This looks cool, but it must be in the Commercial version (or it is harder than it looks).  I could not get it to work with the Community Edition.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working example. It works for .NET 4.0, not sure about other versions...

Comment: That GetField method seems to always return null

Comment: @GFK, which version of .NET are you using? It works in 4.0, but probably not in earlier versions, because the auto-generated name for the event handler field is different (IIRC)

Comment: @Thomas I'm with .NET 4.0, even looking at GetProperties() without arguments I couldn't find anything related to the event. GetEvent finds but I cannot raise it using GetEvent.

Comment: GetProperties has nothing to do with it, you need to use GetField. Could you post some code to illustrate the problem? (post it to Pastebin, not in the comments...)

Comment: With inspiration from this answer I've created a `PropertyChangedEventExtension`, you'll find the extension here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54789191/7108481

Answer (score 3):

Have a go of this http://code.google.com/p/notifypropertyweaver/

All you need to do is implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

So your code will look like

```
public MainFormViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public String StatusText {get; set;}

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
}
```

The build task will **compile** this (you never see the below code)

```
public MainFormViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public String StatusText {get; set;}
    private string statusText;

    public string StatusText 
    {
       get { return statusText; }
       set
       {
           if (value!= statusText)
           {
               statusText = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("StatusText");
           }
       }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By leveraging [EqualityComparer.Default](http://danrigby.com/2012/01/08/inotifypropertychanged-the-anders-hejlsberg-way/) you can reduce the property setter code down to one line as follows:

```
private int unitsInStock;
public int UnitsInStock 
{
  get { return unitsInStock; }
  set { SetProperty(ref unitsInStock, value, "UnitsInStock"); }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, string name) 
{
  if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) 
  {
    field = value;
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) 
    {
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
  }
}
```

If your view models inherit from a base class that defines the `SetProperty` method and the `PropertyChanged` event, then the amount of code required to support INotifyPropertyChanged in your child view models becomes very minimal (1 line).

This approach is more verbose then the code weaving methods mentioned in other answers, but doesn't require you to modify your build process to accomplish it.

Be sure to take a look at the upcoming [C# 5 Caller Info attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540%28VS.110%29.aspx) as well as it looks like they will allow us to avoid using a magic string in the method without the performance cost of reflection.

UPDATE (March 1st, 2012):

The .NET 4.5 Beta is out, and with it, you can further refine the above code to this which removes the need for the string literal in the caller:

```
private int unitsInStock;
public int UnitsInStock
{
    get { return unitsInStock; }
    set 
    { 
        SetProperty(ref unitsInStock, value);
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = "")
{
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
    {
        field = value;
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

I have a [blog post](http://danrigby.com/2012/03/01/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-5-way/) that talks about it in slightly more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Ive always liked this method

```
private string m_myString;
public string MyString
{
    get { return m_myString; }
    set 
    {
        if (m_myString != value)
        {
             m_myString = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged("MyString");
        }
    }
}


private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}
```

or for less code bloat

```
set 
{
    m_myString = value;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("MyString");
}
```

Comment: Val. In a multithreaded application you should take a local copy of PropertyChanged before calling it. The reason being the code "if (PropertyChanged != null)" may pass bu by the time u call PropertyChanged it could be null. Extreme edge case i know but can be very hard to debug.

Comment: I hadn't considered that scenario. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Simon has a good point, but in general property change notifications are only allowed on the UI thread. If the thread that is modifying the `PropertyChanged` event is *not* the same thread that is raising the event, you probably have a bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have a base class called "Model". It exposes a protected object called DataPoints, which is essentially a dictionary.

C#

```
public String StatusText {
    get { 
        return (string)DataPoints["StatusText"]; 
    } 
    set { 
        DataPoints["StatusText"] = value; 
    }
}
```

VB

```
public Property StatusText as String 
    get 
        return DataPoints!StatusText 
    end get 
    set
        DataPoints!StatusText = value
    end set
end property
```

When you set a value in the DataPoints dictionary it does the following:

1. Checks to make sure the value actually changed.
2. Saves the new value
3. Sets the IsDirty property to true.
4. Raises the Property Changed event for the named property as well as the IsDirty and IsValid properties.

Since it is a dictionary, it also makes loading objects from a database or XML file really easy.

Now you may think reading and writing to dictionary is expensive, but I've been doing a lot of performance testing and I haven't found any noticable impact from this in my WPF applications.

Answer (score 0):

The `PropertyChanged.Fody` NuGet package does this.

https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

- Add the `PropertyChanged.Fody` package to your project.
- Reference **PropertyChanged** in your model: `using PropertyChanged;`
- Add the `[ImplementPropertyChanged]` attribute to your class.

All of the properties in the class will now magically implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Note - Fody works by modifying the emitted IL so you will never actually see the code in VS - it just magically does it.

Additional docs:
https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/Attributes